# Emberjs not accepting array from spring mvc properly

Tags: spring-mvc, ember.js, ember-data

I am new to Ember and not very strong in JavaScript.

I am trying to use Java Spring MVC on a back-end with Ember on the front end. When I am trying to access a page. Ember makes a request for data to the server. Server answers with an Array, but the Array is not retrieved on the Ember side properly. I get an exception.

```
Error while loading route: Error: No model was found for '0'
at new Error (native)
at Error.Ember.Error (http://localhost:8080/libs/js/ember.js:844:19)
at Ember.Object.extend.modelFor (http://localhost:8080/libs/js/ember-data.js:9805:33)
at JSONSerializer.extend.extractArray (http://localhost:8080/libs/js/ember-data.js:3172:28)
at superWrapper (http://localhost:8080/libs/js/ember.js:1239:16)
at Ember.Object.extend.extractFindAll (http://localhost:8080/libs/js/ember-data.js:2380:21)
at Ember.Object.extend.extract (http://localhost:8080/libs/js/ember-data.js:2365:37)
at http://localhost:8080/libs/js/ember-data.js:10396:34
at invokeCallback (http://localhost:8080/libs/js/ember.js:9753:19)
at publish (http://localhost:8080/libs/js/ember.js:9423:9)
```

When debuging the javascript i found out that there is for in loop looping over an array

```
 for (var prop in payload)
```

This for in loop is not retrieving the array elements, but is rather going throw properties. It might be because of what they talk about in [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

The - for me - problematic code is on github [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L506).

Am I doing something wrong? should I report a bug?

I have created the following Ember model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
email: DS.attr('string'),
active: DS.attr('boolean'),
});
```

This is how the mapping looks like on server side

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
public
@ResponseBody
List<User> users() {
    System.out.println("getting users");
    List<User> list = new LinkedList<User>();
    list.add(new User(1,"test@b.c"));
    list.add(new User(2,"test2@b.c"));
    list.add(new User(3,"test3@b.c"));
    return list;
}
```

This JSON I got from fiddler:

```
[{"id":1,"email":"test@b.c","active":true},{"id":2,"email":"test2@b.c","active":false},{"id":3,"email":"test3@b.c","active":false}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, I believe ember-data expects your JSON response to be prefixed with the model name, even if it's an array. This means you're data will need to be formatted like this:

```
{
   "users":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "email":"test@b.c",
         "active":true
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "email":"test2@b.c",
         "active":false
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "email":"test3@b.c",
         "active":false
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped, still i don't understand how ember understood that users is plural of the model name user.